# change sql code to eliminate repeating

Tags: sql, coldfusion, repeat

Got a question regarding SQL and ColdFusion: I can't write SQL code properly, so that it won't repeat the variables twice. So far I've got:

```
<cfquery name="get_partner_all" datasource="#dsn#">
    SELECT  
    C.COMPANY_ID,
    C.FULLNAME,
    CP.MOBILTEL,
    CP.MOBIL_CODE, 
    CP.IMCAT_ID,
    CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_TEL, 
    CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_TELCODE,
    CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_TEL_EXT,
    CP.MISSION, 
    CP.DEPARTMENT, 
    CP.TITLE,
    CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_SURNAME, 
    CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_NAME, 
    CP.PARTNER_ID, 
    CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_EMAIL, 
    CP.HOMEPAGE, 
    CP.COUNTY,
    CP.COUNTRY,
    CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_ADDRESS, 
    CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_FAX,
    CC.COMPANYCAT,
    CRM.BAKIYE,
    CRM.BORC,
    CRM.ALACAK
    FROM
        COMPANY_PARTNER CP,
        COMPANY C,
        COMPANY_CAT CC,
        #DSN2_ALIAS#.COMPANY_REMAINDER_MONEY CRM
    WHERE
                C.COMPANY_ID = CP.COMPANY_ID
    AND C.COMPANY_ID = CRM.COMPANY_ID
    AND C.COMPANYCAT_ID = CC.COMPANYCAT_ID
```

As you can see definition `C.COMPANY_ID` is repeated twice, so the variable shown also twice, but I need this (CRM) definition to display some money issues.

Can anyone show me how I can define it in a different way so that the output of this code won't repeat the variables?

Comment: without knowing the schema of tables involved its hard to respond to this but do you mean you are getting rows with repeating c.company_id or the column is showing up twice?

Comment: im getting repeated rows, not the columns, and i modified the select section, but still no change

Comment: I've updated my answer with a few hints of where to look next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean that you get multiple columns in the result set, each with the name "COMPANY_ID". The solution to this is to specify specific columns from all of the tables, instead of `SELECT *` (not just for the `COMPANY_CAT` table, alias `CC`).

---

If you're getting "repeated" rows, then you need to examine the contents of these rows. What's happening there is that one or more rows from another table is matching one row from the "COMPANY" table. Each matching pair of rows generates a row in the output. Now you've expanded your column list, compare a pair of rows which have the same `COMPANY_ID` - in which columns do they differ? If it's in, say, the last 3 columns, then there are multiple rows in `CRM` which match the same `COMPANY_ID`.

Once you've identified the other table that is causing duplicates to occur, you need to decide how to limit them - should you be aggregating values from that table (e.g. `SUM` or `MAX`), or is there a way to further refine which row from the other table you want to match to the row in `COMPANY`.

At a guess though, I'd speculate that one company could have multiple partners...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `select table.*`. Instead, name each column explicitly and don't repeat columns, as follows:

```
select
  c.company_id,
  c.blah_blah,
  -- don't select cp.company_id
  cp.foo_bar,
  -- etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove * and replace with column name list. It is always advisable to write column list instead of * as performance point of view. Also if you are adding any column in database table and using * to get data sometime it will not reflect new column in query result due to caching.

In you case just keep company_id for any one of the table. That's it.